# Using WiFi https site are accessible but not http sites

Tags: android, security, android-wifi, android-wireless

Hi I am using WiFi on Android Tablet.

I am able to access HTTPS sites successfully on any browser on Tablet but when I want to access HTTP sites it says

`Access to Guntella Protocol is blocked according to the policy of the organisation security policy`. How can I reslove this issue.

What is problem ?
Is it there problem in Tablet or in WiFi?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you google about `Gnutella Protocol`?

Comment: Yes I did but didnt find any solutions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is the networks security policy that it does not allow un encrypted traffic?

I do not think that this is a problem with your Tablet, perhaps though there are some network applications that can force HTTPS everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

If it is because of WiFi, you can use WiTuners to decide what types of APs are around. Otherwise, this must be some settings in your tablet.